# ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient with M1 chip

Tags: rust

When I using this command to install `diesel_cli` in MacBook 2021 M1 pro:

```sh
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features mysql postgres sqlite
```

Shows error like this:

```
= note: ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v1.4.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/cargo-installZrtZFh`

Caused by:
    could not compile `diesel_cli` due to previous error
```

I already tried to install mysql-client using this command:

```sh
brew install mysql-client
```

Seems did not fix this problem, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: What happened when you did "brew install mysql-client"? Did you do "brew install mysql"?

Comment: I do not want to install mysql, I just want the diesel works. @hkBst

Comment: The diesel cli, by default, requires libpq, sqlite and mysql. Once these dependencies are installed, you can run cargo install diesel_cli. -- https://lib.rs/crates/diesel_cli